# error: call of overloaded 'node(int&)' is ambiguous|?

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error when I am trying to load my priority queue by calling it
in my function for my binary tree. If I take out the pq.emplace(node(v, ct++)) and just put {ct++} it works. I am just trying to get my pq loaded with my binary tree so I can sort it and print out to screen.

```
class node
{
public:
    node(){left=NULL; right=NULL; ct = 1;}
    node (int v){val = v; left=NULL; right=NULL;  ct=1;}

    node (int Pri=0, int cat=1)
    : val(Pri), ct(cat), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}


    friend bool operator>(//sorts queue by greatest Priority
    const node& x, const node& y) {
    return x.ct > y.ct;
    }

    friend std::ostream&//prints out queue later
    operator<<(std::ostream& os, const node& Pri) {
    return os  <<"my value = "<<Pri.val<<" occured "<<Pri.ct<<" times";
    }

    std::priority_queue<node, std::vector<node>, std::greater<node> > pq;
    void addnode(int v)
{
        if(v==val){pq.emplace(node(v, ct++));}///changed for {ct+++}
        else if(v<val)
            {
                if(left==NULL){left=new node(v);}///error here!!
                else{left->addnode(v);}
            }
         else
        {
                if(right==NULL){right = new node(v);}///error here!!
                else{right->addnode(v);}
        }
    }


    void display()
    {
         if(left!=NULL){left->display();}
             std::cout<<"my value = "<<val<<" occured "<<ct<<" times"<<std::endl;
             if(right!=NULL){right->display();}
    }

    void display_Queue()
    {
            std::cout << "0. size: " << pq.size() << '\n';
            std::cout << "Popping out elements from Pqueue..."<<'\n';
            while (!pq.empty())
            {
            std::cout << pq.top() <<  std::endl;
            pq.pop();
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
    }
private:
int val;      ///value in that node
int ct;      ///ct = count of that value
node * left;
node * right;


};


#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Q7.h"

using namespace std;
int unsortedRemoveDuplicates(vector<int>& numbers)
    {
    set<int> seenNums; //log(n) existence check
    auto itr = begin(numbers);
    while(itr != end(numbers))
    {
        if(seenNums.find(*itr) != end(seenNums)) //seen? erase it
            itr = numbers.erase(itr); //itr now points to next element
        else
        {
            seenNums.insert(*itr);
            itr++;
        }
    }
    return seenNums.size();
    }

int main()
{
    node * root=NULL;
    int v, n;
    vector<int> first;
    vector<int>::iterator fi;
    default_random_engine gen(time(NULL));

    cout<<"how many values? "; cin>>n;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {    (v=gen()%n);
         first.push_back(v);
         cout<<"value "<<v<<" generated"<<endl;
         if(root==NULL){root = new node(v);}
         else{
         root->addnode(v);
         }
    }
    unsortedRemoveDuplicates(first);
    cout<<"Binary Tree in a depth first manner with Duplicates 
          removed!"<<endl; 
    for ( fi = first.begin() ; fi != first.end(); ++fi)     
    {cout<<"Node "<<*fi<<endl;}
cout<<"-------------------"<<endl;
    root->display();
    cout<<"-------------------"<<endl;

    cout<<"-------------------"<<endl;
    root->display_Queue();
    cout<<"-------------------"<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe this the same outcome as is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3858401/695787 -- basically, the default arguments and the function overloading leads to ambiguity as to which version to call.

Comment: you mean between {pq.emplace(node(v, ct++)); and {left=new node(v);}?

Comment: just the `node(v)` is ambiguous. It could either be the one-arg constructor, or the two-arg constructor with a default of `int cat=1`.

Comment: that helped a ton got rid of:      node(){left=NULL; right=NULL; ct = 1;}
       node (int v){val = v; left=NULL; right=NULL;  ct=1;}